# Heineken and Mohamed Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

I was trying to understand the costruction of the Heineken and Mohamed groups.

**(II)** Every proper subgroup of $G$ is subnormal and nilpotent.

**Lemma 1.** If $G$ is a non-nilpotent soluble group satisfying condition (II) and $G'\neq G$, then

(a) If $G=<U, V>$, then $G=V$ or $G=U$

(b) $G/G'=C_{p^{\infty}}$

(c) $G$ is a countable $p$-group.

(d) $(G')^p\neq G'$

**Lemma 2.** Assume that $G$ is a non-abelian group possessing an abelian normal subgroup $N$ of finite exponent $p^k$ such that $G/N=C_{p^{\infty}}$. Then

(a) $G$ is not hypercentral.

(b) $G$ satisfies condition (II) iff there is no subgroup $U\neq G$ s.t. $UN=G$.

The problem I have is on the following

**Corollary 2.** If the hypercentral group $G$ satisfies condition (II), then $G$ is nilpotent.

**Proof.** This follows from statements (b), (d) of Lemma 1  together with statement (a) of Lemma 2.

We assume for a contradiction that $G$ is not nilpotent. By Lemma 1 we have to find a subgroup $N$ with which we can apply Lemma 2 and deducing the contradiction. My question is: how we can find $N$ with the property required by Lemma 2? (When we use the condition (d)?)

**Notation**

$p$ is a prime.

Heineken  & Mohamed, "Trivial Centre and normalizer Condition", Journal of Algebra 10. 368-376 (1968)

Comment: Heineken and Mohamed. What a combination :) +1 for that alone.

Comment: I guess you apply Lemma 2 to $G/(G''(G')^p)$ with $N=G'/(G''(G')^p)$.

Comment: Well, it was pretty easy... Thanks Derek!

Comment: If I had another question on the same paper should I open another question or edit this one adding the second question (so that maybe we can also have a "real" answer)?

Comment: If it's a separate question, then it would be legitimate to start a new question, and that would probably result in more people seeing it. But you should provide a link back to this question.